# My regexp_replace will not work for special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been given a query but the query is not working and still produces special characters.

I am looking to replace any special characters listed. The query also comes with translate function, can someone explain to me what this does with regards to chr10 and chr13?

```
substr(translate(regexp_replace(gjl.description, '[^[ -~]|"', ''), chr(10)||chr(13), ' '),1,240) jel_description
```

Many thanks

Comment: Of course, [documentation can](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm). It replaces all occurences of the character from the first string with the character from the second string, that is on the same position. If no corresponding character found in the second string, it is removed from output. You can write SQL with sample data and look what it does.

Comment: Something to keep in mind when working with regular expressions: they only understand 1 character at a time, they do not understand object names nor assign meaning to character sequences. Thus if your regexp contains "...chr(10)..." the regex engine sees it as *find the character* c *followed by the character* h *followed by the character* r *start data capture followed by character* 1 *followed by character* 0 *end data capture*... It does not see the function **chr** with parameter 10.

Answer (score 0):

It "translates" (replaces) CRLF (carriage return (chr(13)) + line feed (chr(10)) to a space.

```
SQL> select 'abc' || chr(10) || chr(13) || 'def' string from dual;

STRING
--------
abc
 def


SQL> select translate('abc' || chr(10) || chr(13) || 'def', chr(10) || chr(13), ' ') translated_string from dual;

TRANSLA
-------
abc def

SQL>
```